# How to organize hierarchical, modular Java project in Git for Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I've been playing for a while with git subtrees and submodules, but didn't reach expected results. But let's explain the project layout. First of all it is modular Java project. It consists of 14 modules. (For sake of simplicity let's call them MA, MB, MC, and so on). As Eclipse currently can handle only one module per project, each module is, well, a separate project. The complicated part starts right here: some of the modules depends on each other. So let's say MA does not depend on anything, MB depends on MA, MC also depends on MA, MD depends on MB and ME depends on MC and MD. (There are other modules and dependencies, but it is enough to solve just this case). To illustrate this, look below:

```
MA -x
MB -> MA
MC -> MA
MD -> MB
ME -> MC, MD
```

The super project, which actually is some kind of launcher, that encompasses all Mx modules is, technically, also a Java module (let's call it MF). In Eclipse's workspace there are all these MA-MF modules as separate projects (visible as siblings in Project Explorer) that are setup (via Eclipse Java Build Path) to appropriately depends on each other. So it look more or less like:

```
Workspace:
+-- MA/
    +-- ...
+-- MB/
    +-- ...
...
+-- MF/
    +-- ...
```

I was reluctant to create Git repositories for this project, because I wasn't sure what will be the final layout of the project, but since now I settled it, I'd like to add all of these modules do VCS (i.e. Git). But I'd like to maintain each Java module as actually separate repository. Yet I want to checkout MB or MC on it's own and be able to work on in (keeping in mind, that these depend on MA, which should be also somehow checked out). And I want to checkout MD or ME on their own and work on these. But please note, that these depend on other modules hierarchically. The same goes with MF (or other modules that have not been mentioned). And I'd really love to be able to check them out on the same level in FS hierarchy, to satisfy Eclipse. Eclipse can of course handle nested projects and show them in flat view as siblings, but please note MB and MC case, where both depend on MA---I really would like to have the possibility to share worktree (as Git names it) between those two modules (and not to have two separate git instances of MA under MB and MC).

As I mentioned at the beginning, I played for a while with git submodules and subtrees, but I wasn't able to achieve my goals.

I don't mind if the project setup turns out to be complicated, if it is going to be done once. I don't mind if commits and pushes (and branching) would require slightly complicated handling and raised attention while performing. (I don't have to use Eclipse Git plugin, issuing commands via bash is fine).

Alternatively I would gladly hear how do you handle modular Java projects of several levels of dependency between modules in git (and how do you use Eclipse for managing that).

Comment: To ensure that dependent projects fit together, they should be located in the same repository. Alternatively, version the modules and specify the dependencies by version ranges instead of referring directly to other projects (which is more complex). Modules are independent, each with its own dependencies. That's why it doesn't make sense to have multiple modules in one project. In most cases, it makes no sense to structure the modules/projects hierarchically (for what reason would you like to group multiple modules?). Just have a look at how it's been done in OSGi for over a decade.

Comment: See Java JRE modules---they are hierarchical. They can depend on the same other modules. And this perfectly makes sens to me.

Comment: Where are the JRE modules hierarchically grouped into subfolder and subsubfolder? To me, it looks like the modules of the Java standard library are located in the hg repository on the same level. For example, if you have two products, you will probably want to organize the modules into three groups/subfolders: common and two for each of the product-specific modules. And then there will be a third product or a major structural change and the previous grouping doesn't make sense anymore. You only have 14 modules. Start simple.

Comment: Please, read my question more carefully, as certainly you didn't get the point. Dependencies are hierarchical. Layout is not (it is flat). I even drew simple diagram. I have no idea, why do you think the dependency have anything to do with project layout. Never mind, sadly it doesn't seem like you can provide useful hint anyway.

Comment: Please stop being rude. If you want to have the modules/projects in separate Git repositories, you have to make sure in other ways that nobody accidentally works on different versions (e.g. when on one repository a pull was made and on another not). In contrast, in a single Git repository, a commit is an atomic transaction. What is the benefit using separate Git repositories that outweigh the dependencies across Git repositories problem? In Eclipse, for the dependencies via projects (which by the way are not hierarchical but acyclic graphs), it doesn't matter where they are located in the FS.

Comment: I am sorry if I offended you in any way, I didn't mean to. I simply got the impression, that you are talking about something else than I asked for. My bad I actually said "hierarchical dependencies", where in fact, as you pointed it out, these are acyclic graph (as one can see in the diagram). Sticking to a certain version is typical way of handling it (as many tools do), but at this moment all of these modules are being developed all together, so it is more convenient to work on them "versionlessly". When they become mature, it is reasonable to version them. Not now, thou, hence the question.

Comment: What's preventing you from putting all your projects into the same Git repository? I'm using Git repositories > 1 GB on a 10-year-old laptop without any problems. To use Git on the command line in addition to or instead of EGit would make things a bit slower, but that shouldn't be a problem either. With dependencies via projects, Eclipse offers nice things like _Close Unrelated Projects_ in the right-click menu of a project.

Comment: Sooner or later I will have to share some modules with 3rd parties, but some modules need to stay "private". Hence the need of the split. On the other hand some of modules will be used for internal tools, so I need these to be separate from the main project. (Some of these tools, who knows, may even evolve into fully fledged apps on their own conditions). It's, after all, what modules are for, right? I just stuck with organizing repos and projects that is cunning enough not to force anyone joining the project to juggle with settings, remotes and dependencies too much...

Comment: When the time comes, delete the public projects in the internal repository and put them into a new separate repository. You certainly don't want to share the history before the time making it public. If you share some modules with 3rd parties, explicit versioning is unavoidable, and dependencies cross internal and public modules have to be made via versioned JARs/bundles/modules/artifacts/whatever instead of via projects containing the source code.